# Defining functions on scope from a remote controller on the same server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a project, which is like a framework which renders data defined in layouts (screens) in format of jsons. For example, i will write ,

```
{
     Name : "First Name", 
     Row : "1" ,
     Type: "Text Box"
}
```

It will render a Text Box with label "First Name".

I have central service which is the root scope of entire framwork. 
My requirement is -

1. User/Developer will write his own controller and html on the same server outside of the Framework code.
2. To this controller i will pass my `$scope` and he will define his new methods and he will also provide a html which i need to render.
3. This html will use the functions on the scope which can be either from my f/w or his controller.

I have explored -

1. Angular ajax - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/ajax.html
2. Angoose - https://github.com/tjworks/angoose

I am not sure if my design is correct. Do i need to do it in a completely different way ? OR there is way to achieve what i have designed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can simply create reusable directive which will do all these things for others. user/developer will use this directive depending on their needs.

Comment: Javascript and RMI have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @jad-panda , the question of calling a remote method still remains, the code he/she will write is outside of where the framework is deployed , may be on the same server but outside.

Comment: @EJP .. sorry for the incorrect tag , thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0):

If any one stumbles on this question , this how we solved it

Our application build structure was maven related. So we placed these custom services and html on the same server and wrote a automation program to include these files based on the inputs in properties files.

Once this inclusion was out of the way , angular injector did the rest of adding the service dynamically and html was 'ng-include'-ed.

For those who would like to explore completely angular based solution please check out -

https://github.com/ifyio/angularjs-lazy-loading-with-requirejs